# how to group each and order by the max

Tags: oracle

i have two tables, it's table a and b,

table a

```
id      customer_code     invoice_id
uuid1        c1                 5
uuid2        c2                 2
uuid3        c3                 3
uuid4        c2                 6
uuid5        c1                 4
uuid6        c2                 1
```

table b

```
id      invoice_no        create_date           
1       i001        2018-07-01  10:00:00         
6       i002        2018-07-05  15:00:00         
5       i003        2018-07-03  15:00:00         
4       i004        2018-07-11  15:00:00         
2       i005        2018-07-04  15:00:00         
3       i006        2018-07-06  15:00:00
```

it's get the each customer the order. each customer only get the max date and order by it asc.

result:

```
customer_code        create_date
c2              2018-07-05  15:00:00
c3              2018-07-06  15:00:00
c1              2018-07-11  15:00:00
```

i want to get the finally result as below.it's must be the same order as the result, how to write the SQL?

final result

```
customer_code  
c2              
c3            
c1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the join condition between the two table is that `b.id` matches `a.invoice_id`, then it's a simple join with aggregation:

```
select a.customer_code, max(b.create_date)
from a
join b on b.id = a.invoice_id
group by a.customer_code;

CUSTOMER_CODE CREATE_DATE        
------------- -------------------
c3            2018-07-06 15:00:00
c1            2018-07-11 15:00:00
c2            2018-07-05 15:00:00
```

which has an indeterminate order; so you need an order-by clause, which can either use positional notation with `order by 2` or, more usefully here given the end goal, can repeat the aggregate expression:

```
select a.customer_code, max(b.create_date) as create_date
from a
join b on b.id = a.invoice_id
group by a.customer_code
order by max(b.create_date);

CUSTOMER_CODE CREATE_DATE        
------------- -------------------
c2            2018-07-05 15:00:00
c3            2018-07-06 15:00:00
c1            2018-07-11 15:00:00
```

You can order by an expression that isn't in the select list - as long as it would be valid there, so an aggregate or a column in the group-by - so you can just omit the date aggregate from the select list if you only want to see the customer code:

```
select a.customer_code
from a
join b on b.id = a.invoice_id
group by a.customer_code
order by max(b.create_date);

CUSTOMER_CODE
-------------
c2
c3
c1
```